# Start and stop my react app client/ server using npm scripts, but starts the server only

Tags: reactjs, npm-scripts

I would like to start and stop my react app using single command to start the server and client using npm scripts. I have below folder structure under src directory:

```
src/client/components
src/server/server.js file
```

I have tried below, but this is just starting the server but not the client, how do I fix this ? Is there any other better solution other than this, as I need to start and stop running my react website in Vultr server ?

```
 "scripts": {
    "start-run": "node src/server/server.js && npm run start-client",
    "start-client": "react-scripts start"
  }
```

[image]

Comment: You cant start client and server normally with npm, if you want to start client and server concurrently you need to install a module called “concurrently”